# Struts mapping exception

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am getting a exception while start the system.but system could continue with that exception. Doc type definition is in the struts config XML.

```
2013-07-02 11:35:27,891 ERROR [org.apache.commons.digester.Digester] Parse Error at line 32761 column 21: The content of element type "action-mappings" must match "(action)*".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "action-mappings" must match "(action)*".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1745)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:944)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:465)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

struts-config.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN"
        "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_1.dtd">

<struts-config>
  <!--configurations -->
 </struts-config>
```

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Post the contents of `<action-mappings>`.

Comment: It's really big list,I couldn't post everything here, it contains and <actions-mappings>  and <form-beans>

Comment: Lol, then how do you expect anyone to help?! The problem is obvious anyway, you have something other than what the DTD allows (stated in the exception) in your action mappings element (as stated in the exception).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't follow the [DTD specification](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-core/dtddoc/struts-config_1_3.dtd.html) for Struts1. You need to follow the structure defined there.

`<action-mappings>` should contain only `<action>` as direct childs. `<form-beans>` should be a child of `<struts-config>`.

Also, if you're building a new project, beware of the End Of Life status this project reached on 2013-04-05, see [announcement](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html).